# Does a theoretical "perfect (accuracy) score" exists we could target for a given dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, algorithms

My question is the following :

You have a dataset, and you want to determine theoretically what accuracy score (or other way to measure performance such as AUC, etc.) a "perfect" model could get on test data (or : what average accuracy score you would get with new data). You don't want to find the model, but just what is the best score you can achieve. It is a bit the same than for computer science where you know an algorithm can have a computational complexity of n but you don't know what algorithm. Or in mathematics where you prove something can be proved but you don't prove the actual theorem.

Let's take an example :

I struggle with a dataset, having poor results. I'm not sure if my poor results come from the fact that I'm a noob and/or it is not possible to infer more from the dataset. So if I could compute what theoretically I could get (X % accuracy score) then I could see if I'm doing well or not.

---

I know the accuracy score depends on data, which data you took for training and test sets respectively, but maybe we could consider accuracy score as the mean accuracy score. Hope this is not a duplicate nor a (completely) dumb question.

Comment: If you're talking about training set performance, you can always get a perfect result if the modeling method is sufficiently flexible, unless you have duplicate instances with different class labels. Bounding generalization performance (= unseen test set performance) is a different story with no generally applicable solution.

Comment: @MarcClaesen : I meant what you call "Bounding generalization performance", I guess ! The idea is "what score in average would you get on unseen data ?".

Comment: Impossible to say without trying. However, it is possible to compute certain lower bounds, for example [the unachievable region in precision-recall space](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3858955/pdf/nihms379744.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [VC dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VC_dimension://) can give an upper bound on the probability of test error for a given model and number of training examples. However, this is a pretty esoteric area of study and might not be easily calculated for your intended application.

A somewhat accessible intro to this can be found at the bottom of [this page.](http://work.caltech.edu/library/)

Comment: Sorry for replying late, thanks for your answer ! Based on your link I could discover the caltech course a few months ago, so I thank you for that I found it awesome!

Comment: The reference to the Cal.Tech webpage is great.